# Django SECRET KEY error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-settings, django-2.0

I'm building a little Django REST API. I've configured a separate settings module for local and production but I'm having an annoying error which is:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting
>   must not be empty.

This error doesn't make sense because I have the SECRET_KEY variable set. Here are my base.py (which is my base settings for the API) and the local.py. Also, here are my wsgi.py and manage.py.

**base.py**

```
"""
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""
import datetime
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
from django.conf import settings

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'mmglfamx3n927*93$ks#r)h%*a(@))vb7*=2q$&z(=6@q&*ghj')

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api',
    'drf_yasg',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'petevip.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'petevip.wsgi.application'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.Shop'

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
        'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
        'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
        'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
        'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
        'api.utils.jwt_payload.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=6000),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': None,

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,

}

SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
}
```

**local.py**

```
from petevip.settings.base import *

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'petevip_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'DvCglg&282300*kwzsk^x14c3qB4%F2eCMn8',
        'HOST': '172.17.0.2',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefaul("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "petevip.settings.local")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**manage.py**

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "petevip.settings.local")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Also this is my folder structure:

```
petevip-api/
 |-- petevip/
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- settings/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- base.py
 |    |    |-- local.py
 |    |    +-- production.py
 |    |-- urls.py
 |    +-- wsgi.py
 +-- manage.py
```

If anyone can help me with this problem I will be very glad! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Error full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 26, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 254, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 47, in add_arguments
    test_runner_class = get_runner(settings, self.test_runner)
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 304, in get_runner
    test_runner_class = settings.TEST_RUNNER
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-api/petevip/settings/local.py", line 1, in <module>
    from petevip.settings.base import *
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-api/petevip/settings/base.py", line 127, in <module>
    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/albertdiaz/development/petevip-project/petevip-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 125, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Comment: Setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['']` could cause issues, but that's probably not the problem here. The default is `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []`.

Comment: Is this happening locally? I see this error when django doesn't know what settings files to point at, so test it with `python manage.py runserver --settings=petevip.settings.local` to see if it runs.

Comment: Is that the actual content of your `base.py`? The first line is a URL and the rest is a huge multi-line string and not code.

Comment: @kichik nop, I've edited right now, my bad.

Comment: @Alasdair nice to known, I'll try that this isn't the error.

Comment: @markwalker_ I've tried and I have the same error.

Comment: Does your `settings/__init__.py` contain anything?

Comment: @Alasdair nop, there are empty

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: You should change your database password and secret key after posting them here. Hackers can use those to compromise your website.

Comment: @kichik thanks for the advice. I've already changed :)

Comment: @Alasdair done!

Comment: Hey, I realise this is old, but is there any chance you're running this through an IDE (like pycharm)?

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you have an env variable `SECRET_KEY` set to an empty string. Check if this is the case:

```
$ env | grep SECRET_KEY
SECRET_KEY=
```

If this is what you get, then you have probably tried to clear the env var by issuing

```
$ export SECRET_KEY=
```

This will not remove the variable, but instead set its value to an empty value. To remove the variable, issue

```
$ unset SECRET_KEY
```

Verify the variable is removed by issuing `env | grep SECRET_KEY` again, this time the output should be empty.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know if this was the error.

Comment: I've tried, and the variable SECRET_KEY is empty for sure. But I'm having the same error

Comment: How do i check if there is a SECRET_KEY environment variable set in windows?

Comment: @AjitGoel check out [How can I display the contents of an environment variable from the command prompt in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/341192)

Comment: @hoefling, is environment variables being set in the computer, the same as setting an environment variable(SECRET_KEY) in Django? I am asking as I got an error when I ran the "env | grep SECRET_KEY
SECRET_KEY=" command

Comment: @AjitGoel 1. the command is `env | grep SECRET_KEY`. The line after command is its output. 2. This command is for Unix shell and won't work on Windows. 3. There is no environment variable `SECRET_KEY` in Django, it's part of the OP's code. It may not be relevant for your app at all.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else ends up here. For me the issue was that I was running the local run server through PyCharm.

PyCharm sets the setting module as an environment variable over riding your manage.py file. To fix this I had to open the run configurations and edit the Environment variables.

Just check that your IDE isn't doing anything sneaky if you're having trouble with the settings file.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.conf import settings
```

You shouldn’t be importing settings inside settings. Remove the import, and use `SECRET_KEY` instead of `settings.SECRET_KEY`